# Getting values from UISliders with tags

Tags: objective-c, tags, slider

**Introduction**

I've created a bunch of sliders with a loop. I now want to retrieve their values when a button is pushed. There seems to be some issue which is causing the app to crash, I'm not really sure what's going wrong

**Code**

*Defining slider tags*

```
slider1.tag = count;
count += 1;  
[subView addSubview:slider1];
```

*Retrieving slider values*

```
-(void) build:(id)sender {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        UISlider *Slider = (UISlider*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        NSLog(@"%f",Slider.value);
    }
}
```

**Logs**

*I'm guessing this means that the slider isn't found, but why is this happening?*

> 2014-07-25 17:18:49.911 App1.0[5155:a0b] -[UIView value]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x109a44f00
>
> 2014-07-25 17:18:49.913 App1.0[5155:a0b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109a44f00'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ae8795 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010184b991 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000101b79bad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ada09d
>   ___forwarding_** + 973    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101ad9c48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   Dream1.0
>   0x0000000100001d8d -[TemplateViewController build:] + 173     6   UIKit
>   0x00000001004af096 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
>     7   UIKit                               0x00000001004af044
>   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100583450 -[UIControl
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203   9   UIKit                               0x00000001005829c0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530   10 
>   UIKit                               0x00000001007b3c3d
>   _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5149     11  UIKit                               0x00000001004e3925 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928     12  UIKit
>   0x00000001004e45e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 910   13  UIKit
>   0x00000001004bdfa2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211  14  UIKit
>   0x00000001004abd7f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9549  15 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a77ec1
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a77792
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242   17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a9361f __CFRunLoopRun + 767     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000101a92f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467     19  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010311b3a0 GSEventRunModal + 161  20  UIKit
>   0x00000001004ae043 UIApplicationMain + 1010   21  Dream1.0
>   0x0000000100005903 main + 115     22  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000103dc37e1 start + 0 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `viewWithTag:` doesn't return UISlider every time.
In first loop iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
```

i is equal 0 and 0 is a default value, so every UIView subclass (in the view controller) you haven't change the tag property has that value set to 0, for example the button you press.

One of the solution is to set up your UISlider tag from 1 not 0 and you should enumerate from 1 when you retrieve the slider, you should do also safety chack to make sure you have UISlider:

// First value of count should be 1, not 0:
// You can set it in init method or before loop count = 1;

```
slider1.tag = count;
count += 1;  
[subView addSubview:slider1];

-(void) build:(id)sender {
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
        UIView *v = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]) {
            UISlider *Slider = (UISlider*)v;
            NSLog(@"%f",Slider.value);
        }
    }
}
```